# Sou obrigado a entregar meu código fonte se eu usar biblioteca gpl?

Tags: licença, gpl

Se eu usar algumas bibliotecas gpl no meu código fonte e escrever toda a minha aplicação, porém usando algumas bibliotecas para algumas funções específicas do meu sistema eu tenho que entregar o código fonte da minha aplicação toda se alguém pedir ou tenho que entregar apenas as modificações e correções que eu fizer na biblioteca?

Por exemplo, se eu tivesse criado um sistema ERP completo, mas para imprimir tivesse usado uma biblioteca que é gpl eu teria que fornecer só as correções se existissem da biblioteca gpl ou teria que entregar meu software completo?

A empresa que não entrega o código fonte está pirateado?

Comment: Sim, é obrigado. Eu conheço ERP bem conhecido que usa (ou usava, não posso afirmar se ainda usa) que é irregular por causa disto :)

Comment: Isso só por ter uma biblioteca GPL, ou seja mesmo que ela seja menos de 1% do seu projeto, se usou por consequência o seu software é automaticamente GPL também. (não falo da LGPL, mas da GPL mesmo). Por isso que é chamado de efeito viral?

Comment: Sim, exatamente isto. É o que se chama de licença viral. Ou seja, de livre ela não tem nada.

Comment: @Maniero pelo contrário, acho realmente que essa é livre, se uma empresa quiser ganhar dinheiro ela que se esforce para desenvolver do zero e não usar o que o pessoal já fez, quem faz um Software e licencia em GLP quer que o trabalho seja evoluído que alguém abrace a ideia e de continuidade.

Comment: Uma licença que te obriga fazer algo é livre? Tenho uma interpretação diferente. Na verdade se ler direito o que acabou de descrever, mostra claramente falta de liberdade. Até o criador dessa licença não estabelece relação entre ela e dinheiro. O que é algo muito esquisito porque os maiores beneficiados deste tip ode licença são as grandes corporações que economizam ou mesmo fazem muito dinheiro por elas existirem.